# User cannot access a share folder, even when account is member of a Full Control group for the Share

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, file-permissions, windows-storage-server

Last week, I set up Windows Storage Server 2012 for a customer. I'm not normally a sys admin, so it was a fun bit of learning.

I created 3 Shares for the customer and a number of user groups that have different permissions on those shares. The lead customer is a member of the "Core Staff" group which, on all three shares, is given Full Control, in both the Share and NTFS permissions settings areas. On all three shares, "All Users" have no access.

The issue is, this user account is able to open and modify Share1 and Share2. the user is not, however, able to modify Share3, even though as far as I can tell, the permissions and settings are the same.

I'm wondering if anyone can offer troubleshooting guidance, or if I just need to have him (I'm remote and they won't allow me an account that I can remote in with) delete the share and recreate it?

Comment: Why the down-vote on this without a comment? I'd have pulled it or rewritten it if I violated the site or posting rules somewhere. If it was about research effort, I was through the permissions on all the folders multiple times in both the admin and in the file explorer, and couldn't find this question asked elsewhere on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few real options here, assuming you're getting an "access denied."

1. The share permissions are wrong on Share3
2. The NTFS permissions are wrong on Share3
3. There is an over-riding Deny ACE on the NTFS permissions for Share3.

Check, double check, and triple check. If Share1 and Share2 work and the same group gives access to all three, then the problem must be on an ACL for Share3.

Comment: What's happening is the user goes to the remote server in file explorer "\\SERVER-FOO", is presented with an authentication challenge and passes it, then tries opening the folder (double-click "Share3"), and it presents the auth challenge again and won't accept the user account credentials.

Comment: It must have been something missed on my part. I've had him rebuild the share from scratch (it wasn't being used yet) and it's working now. Thanks for the feedback!